Create MultiPolygon objects from struct type and list[list[list[f64]]] columns using Polars
I have downloaded the NYC Taxi Zones dataset (downloaded from SODA Api and saved as json file - Not GeoJson or Shapefile). The dataset is rather small, thus I am using the whole information included. For the convenience of the post I am presenting the first 2 rows of the dataset:

original (with struct type value of the_geom).
dataset after unpacking the struct type with unnest() command in polars. --updated with write_ndjson() command

The original dataset:

Below the dataset after applying unnest() and selecting some columns and the first 2 rows.

You may import the data using polars with the following command
import polars as pl
poc = pl.read_json("./data.json"))

I am interested in the multipolygons. I am actually trying to re-calculate the shape_area by using the multipolygon and wkt (Well-Known-Text representation) - method used by shapely module.
What I have done so far is to use the column coordinates and transform it to a MultiPolygon() object - readable by the Shapely module.
def flatten_list_of_lists(data):
    return [subitem3 for subitem1 in data for subitem2 in subitem1 for subitem3 in subitem2]

The function takes as input a list[list[list[list[f64]]]] object and transforms to a list[list[f64]] object.
flattened_lists = [flatten_list_of_lists(row) for row in poc["coordinates"].to_list()]

print(flattened_lists)


[[[-74.18445299999996, 40.694995999999904], [-74.18448899999999, 40.69509499999987], [-74.18449799999996, 40.69518499999987], [-74.18438099999997, 40.69587799999989], [-74.18428199999994, 40.6962109999999], [-74.18402099999997, 40.69707499999989]...

Then I use the function below that applies string concatenation and basically:

Transforms the list[list[f64]] object to String.
Adds the keyword MultiPolygon in front of the string.
Replaces '[' and ']' with '('., ')' respectively.

def polygon_to_wkt(polygon):
    # Convert each coordinate pair to a string formatted as "lon lat"
    coordinates_str = ", ".join(f"{lon} {lat}" for lon, lat in polygon)
    # Format into a WKT Multipolygon string (each polygon as a single polygon multipolygon)
    return f"""MULTIPOLYGON ((({coordinates_str})))"""

formatted_wkt = [polygon_to_wkt(polygon) for polygon in flattened_lists]
poc = poc.with_columns(pl.Series("WKT", formatted_wkt))


Finally, I use the method wkt.loads("MultiPolygon ((()))").area to compute the shape area of the Multipolygon object
def convert_to_shapely_area(wkt_str):
    try:
        return wkt.loads(wkt_str).area
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error converting to WKT:", e)
        return None
poc = poc.with_columns(
    pl.col("WKT").map_elements(convert_to_shapely_area).alias("shapely_geometry")
)
print(poc.head())


Even though for the first shape the WKT correctly returns the area of the object, while for the second MultiPolygon the methods returns the following error:

IllegalArgumentException: Points of LinearRing do not form a closed linestring

What I have noticed between the two rows, is that the multipolygon of Newark Airport is a continues object of list[list[f64]]] coordinates. Whereas, the Jamaika Bay has multiple sublists [list[list[f64]]] elements (check column coordinates to verify this). Also the screenshot below verify this statement.

Thus, is there any way to unify the multipolygons of Jamaica Bay into one single GEOmetric object before applying WKT?
P.S: Many solutions on GitHub use the shape file, but I would like to regularly re-download the NYC zones automatically with the SODA API.
To download the raw .json file from SODA API (omit logger_object lets pretend it's print())
import requests
params = {
        "$limit": geospatial_batch_size, #i.e. 50_000
        "$$app_token": config.get("api-settings", "app_token")
    }
    response = requests.get(api_url, params=params)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()
        if not data:
            logger_object.info("No data found, please check the API connection.")
            sys.exit()
        with open("{0}/nyc_zone_districts_data.json".format(geospatial_data_storage), "w") as f:
            json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
    else:
        logger_object.error("API request failed.")
        logger_object.error("Error: {0}".format(response.status_code))
        logger_object.error(response.text)


Did you use .write_json() to generate those files? Perhaps you can use .write_ndjson() instead? Currently, I get a single column named columns that is a list of structs - and due to schema enforcement, lots of data is dropped/nulled.

Yes I used the write_json() method. The original dataset has the struct types.. The second dataset (second bullet in SO) has the unnest() sample with list[list[list.. That's why I suggested to use the second dataset and not the original. I just posted the original to give an overview of how the data are downloaded from the SODA Api

Yeah, but if you try to read_json either file you end up with a single list[struct[4]] column named columns.

Hmmm thats weird. And you suggest to use write_ndjson()? Let me try it and update the link of the dataset

write_json adds in Polars metadata. write_ndjson is one approach that produces just the raw data. (I did download the original taxi file from the API but Polars raises a PanicException - I guess due to the empty "format": {} keys)

I have updated the question with the SODA API call in case you wander how I downloaded the raw file. Let me check now the ndjson() in polars

@jqurious Uploaded the new GoogleDrive path

That works - I can load data_unnseted.json as expected, thanks. (Maybe you want to do the same for data.json)

I will thanks for the comment. The original dataset has this struct type format which is not ideal to manipulate with shapely.

I'm not fully following your input or expected output, but regarding the multipolygon construction + the area, you can simply use from shapely.geometry import shape;[shape(x).area for x in poc["the_geom"]] or poc["the_geom"].map_elements(lambda x: shape(x).area) right after reading the original json. No need for any extra string processing.

@Timeless's approach works for me - perhps you can confirm and they can add it as an answer?

I have eventually found a solution for this problem. As already described I am flattening the list of coordinates (a.k.a Points). A point in geospatial data is a (x,y) coordinate. Thus, a MultiPolygon is a combination of multiple Points.
def flatten_list_of_lists(data) -> list:
    return [subitem2 for subitem1 in data for subitem2 in subitem1]

, this abovementioned function is important because the object data used as input argument is of type [list[list[list[f64]]]] and a MultiPolygon has a specific cardinality level per point.
Then I transform its flattened list to a MultiPolygon object using shapely
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, MultiPolygon, Point
def transform_polygons_to_multipolygons(flat_list:list) -> list:
    return [ MultiPolygon( [Polygon(coord) for coord in polygon]).wkt for polygon in  flat_list]

You will notice that after creating each MultiPolygon object I save it to WKT format (thus as a string).
Finally, I compute the area of the multipolygon
from shapely import wkt
def compute_geo_areas(multipolygons:MultiPolygon) -> float:
    return wkt.loads(multipolygons).area

The final code
flattened_lists:list = [flatten_list_of_lists(row) for row in df_geo["coordinates"].to_list()]
multipolygons:list = transform_polygons_to_multipolygons(flattened_lists)

df_geo = df_geo.with_columns(pl.Series("multipolygons", multipolygons)) \
.with_columns(polygon_area=pl.col("multipolygons").map_elements(compute_geo_areas)) \
.drop("coordinates")

, where df_geo is the Polars DataFrame loaded from the JSON file attached on the SO question.
